# What is the correct way to use and logical operator in python for multiple conditions?

Tags: python, logical-operators, brute-force

I'm trying to brute-force a projecteuler questions before I improve my code. I can't get multiple condition and logical operator working in my loop. Here is the code, editor shows no errors but it simply don't increase condition value so obviously some of the conditions are wrong. Can some one show me the correct way to use multiple and logical operators?

```
i = 20

while (i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 4 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and
     i % 6 != 0 and i % 7 != 0 and i % 8 != 0 and i % 9 != 0 and
     i % 10 != 0 and i % 11 != 0 and i % 12 != 0 and i % 13 != 0 and
     i % 14 != 0 and i % 15 != 0 and i % 16 != 0 and i % 17 != 0 and
     i % 18 != 0 and i % 19 != 0 and i % 20 != 0):
    i = i + 20
else:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `and` means **all** of the conditions have to be true - which they obviously can't be (even if you reduce it down to just `i % 2` and `i % 3` they're never going to be both not `0`) - what are you actually trying to do here!?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy `6 % 2` and `6 % 3` both equal 0 ... Of course, for _all_ of  these to equal zero you'd be getting into some pretty big numbers. . .

Comment: if i was 0 it would be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find the smallest number which is a multiple of all integers from 1 to 20 inclusive.  You're starting with 20, and you want to keep going up by 20 until your condition is met.

It's easier to see the problem in a smaller case.  Say we only cared about 2, 3, and 4.

We want to find a number i for which

```
i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i % 4 == 0
```

But the negation of this is either

```
not (i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i % 4 == 0)
```

or, distributing the `not`,

```
i % 2 != 0 or i % 3 != 0 or i % 4 != 0
```

In other words, if *any* of the numbers fail to divide evenly, you want to increase by 20, not if *all* of them fail to.

20, for example, is divisible by 2, so `i % 2 != 0` is False, so you have `False and i % 3 != 0 and.. etc`, which will still be false.  A working version of your code would look like

```
i = 20
while any(i % num != 0 for num in range(2,21)):
    i += 20
```

where I've used a generator expression to avoid all the duplication.  Note thought that this will be *very much* slower than using the math trick they want you to use, because the final answer has 9 digits..

Comment: Thank you. I was searching how to input multiple conditions via logic operator to brute-force this problem before writing this code and now that I see your suggestion I noticed I made a very big mistake. The code I was looking at wasn't in python and I mistakenly taken "| |" in another language as "and" in python when "&&" was the equivalent of "and" and "| |" as "or". Now everything makes sense, again thank you.